# How to delay a JMS message in queue before a listener receives it using camel?

Tags: jms, apache-camel

I am trying to delay a message to be in queue for few seconds.
But when I use camel delay option, it is not delaying in queue, instead it is immediately consumed, and delaying in the route path.
How can we delay messages so that they will be there in queue for few seconds?

My spring with camel configuration looks like below.

```
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">  

    <route id="routeOne" delayer="10000">               
        <from uri="jms://queueone?concurrentConsumers=1"/>          
        <log message="routeOne incoming message ${body}"/>              
        <delay><constant>30000</constant></delay>                       
        <process ref="loggerProcessor"/>                        
    </route>

</camelContext> 

<bean id="loggerProcessor" name="loggerProcessor" class="emh.LoggerProcessor"/>
```

Comment: Some JMS implementations support delayed message delivery. Which one are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Delay via Camel

Camel **delay** and **throttle** will remove (consume) the message from ActiveMQ queue and keep it (in-memory) in the route until processed. Transacted JMS might alleviate issues concerning losing the message, haven't tried that yet. [Food for thought](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/shutting-down-Camel-in-flight-messages-gone-td5717930.html).

---

#### Delay via ActiveMQ

I got it to work in Spring Boot 2 with Camel and ActiveMQ using the `AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY` header combined with enabling `schedulerSupport` [[1](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37462416/2678078), [3](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Howto-use-delay-message-brokerage-in-a-Camel-Route-using-AMQ-SCHEDULED-DELAY-td4282763.html), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995638/delay-delivery-of-message-in-activemq-in-spring-boot), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843682/activemq-override-scheduled-message), [6](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Howto-use-delay-message-brokerage-in-a-Camel-Route-using-AMQ-SCHEDULED-DELAY-td4282763.html)]. This is per [JMS 2.0 Delivery Delay](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html).

Note that a message will only appear in the ActiveMQ queue (*pending*) when there are no active consumers - i.e. application down or Camel route disabled. Configuration below is for using an *existing* ActiveMQ broker.

**application.properties** ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-activemq))

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
```

**RouteBuilder**

```
from("jms://incomingQueue").setHeader("AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY", constant("1000")).inOnly("jms://delayedQueue");  

from("jms://delayedQueue").process(...);
```

**activemq.xml** (existing broker installation)

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulerSupport="true">
```

*For OSX Homebrew found under `/usr/local/Cellar/activemq/<version>/libexec/conf`.*

---

If you want to use a broker *embedded* in your application you can use the **BrokerService**.

By default data is persisted in *activemq-data* and requires the `activemq-kahadb-store` dependency - also if you chose JDBC ([source](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Are-Scheduled-Messages-persistent-td4665977.html)). Using `brokerService.setPersistent( false )` the store dependency is no longer required, but then the JMS message is stored in-memory *again*.

```
@Bean
public BrokerService brokerService()
{
    BrokerService brokerService = new BrokerService();
    brokerService.setSchedulerSupport( true );
    return brokerService;
}
```

Further examples can be found [here](https://github.com/tarka/Camel-Async-Test/blob/amq-delay-header/src/main/resources/applicationContext-amq.xml) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282291/activemq-scheduler-message-in-spring).

Comment: Note that it appears Camel 2.18.1 is the last version working with Spring Boot 2, with official support planned for Camel 2.22.0 ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49577672/2678078)).

Answer (score 0):

Camel has built in support for the Throttler patter, there's a throttler component. Refer: http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html

Simply add the following to the route and that should delay the message.

```
<throttle timePeriodMillis="30000">
```

Comment: throttle is fetching message from Queue and keep it in route exchange and wait for the delay. if we close the application before the delay then we will lose the message