# ActiveMQ scheduler message in spring

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

1.under below configuration, scheduler messages are received immediately.

2.if  removing the annotation`@Profile("embedded")` of `brokerService()`,it will throw a `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind exception`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MessageConfig {
    private static final String DEFAULT_BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";

    public static final String DESTINATION_FB = "fb";
    private static final String USER_NAME = "admin";
    private static final String USER_PASSWORD = "admin";

    @Profile("embedded")
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public BrokerService brokerService() throws Exception {
        BrokerService brokerService = new BrokerService();
        brokerService.setSchedulerSupport(true);
        brokerService.addConnector(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
        return brokerService;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
         /*  connectionFactory.setUserName(USER_NAME);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(USER_PASSWORD);*/
        connectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(Arrays.asList("com.test.test", "java.lang"));
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory factory) {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(factory);
        template.setDefaultDestinationName(DESTINATION_FB);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer containerFactory = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        containerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return containerFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's fine when i change my broker url  such as `61617`,but the web console no longer can monitor the statistics. if i change the `ActiveMQ` config of `transportConnector`,it throws the same exception again.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951330/2678078) answer. With `BrokerService` you can create an *embedded* ActiveMQ, which I suspect explains the address already in use. For *existing* ActiveMQ I need only `spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616` (Spring Boot 2).