# Migrated Spring boot 1.5 to 2.0, unable to start app getting: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver

Tags: java, spring-boot, migration

I upgraded my existing working Spring Boot application, from springboot 1.5 to 2.0.
Now, I am getting below error message, when I try to deploy the application.
Please help.

Note: I don't have @ComponentScan, instead I am using @SpringBootApplication at root package in my application. Also, I am using the latest version of apache camel springboot dependencies.

Also, if I remove the below dependency, the application deploys fine, but ofcourse, without Apache Camel router initialized!

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.2</version>
</dependency>
```

How I did update: Changed the springboot version in pom.xml
Tool used: STS (Spring Tool Suite)

```
14-03-2018 11:51:27.972-main-ERROR-SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.test.MyTestApp]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.apache.camel.spring.boot.health.HealthCheckRoutesAutoConfiguration due to org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:616)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:548)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at com.test.MyTestApp.main(MyTestApp.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.apache.camel.spring.boot.health.HealthCheckRoutesAutoConfiguration due to org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:55)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:217)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:606)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.isEnabled(HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.java:49)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.evaluate(HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.GroupCondition.getMatchOutcome(GroupCondition.java:40)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Contents of pom.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>my-application</name>
    <description>TEST Application</description>

    <!-- Spring 1.5 to 2.0 Migration -->
    <!-- <parent> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version> <relativePath /> lookup parent from repository 
        </parent> -->

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 1.5 to 2.0 Migration -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId> <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-java-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>./src/main/generated-sources</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


        <finalName>test-app</finalName>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: It looks like the version of Camel you are using doesn't like Spring Boot 2.0. Can you post your Spring Boot configuration class?

Comment: I'm loading the configurations from application.properties

Comment: Is it the default file or did you modify it?

Comment: Got this resolved.The Apache Camel 2.20.2 is supported for spring boot 1.5 only. As per Apache Camel website, they will extend support to spring boot starting with 2.22 (early summers 2018). So to resolve, just need to use spring boot 1.5.10 only for now. Thanks all for checking / responding.

Comment: Hi Codeit - can you please answer your own question - this issue will arise more frequently in the next time I suppose ;) Also please set links to the related camel pages for versions 2.21.0 (current latest version) and 2.22.0 - thx.

Comment: Done, thanks. I am new, just now figured, I can answer my own question.. : )

Answer (score 7):

Got this resolved.The Apache Camel 2.20.2 is supported for spring boot 1.5 only. As per Apache Camel website, they will extend support to spring boot starting with 2.22 (early summers 2018). So to resolve, just need to use spring boot 1.5.10 only for now. Thanks all for checking / responding.
Reference Links: http://camel.apache.org/camel-2210-release.html

```
"This release supports only Spring Boot 1.5.x. Support for Spring Boot 2.0.x is coming in Camel version 2.22 which is planned for early summer 2018."
```

P.S. At http://start.spring.io/ **(Switch to the full version)** you can check if a Spring Project(Apache Camel) is compatible with your Spring Boot version. Currently the Initilizer shows

```
Apache Camel
Integration using Apache Camel
requires Spring Boot >=1.4.0.RELEASE and <2.0.0.M1
```

Comment: Spring Boot 2 seems to work up to Camel 2.18.1. Personally I rather downgrade Camel than Spring Boot. Source: [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299069/spring-boot-apache-camel-mongodb-integration-issue/49301572#comment85631196_49301572).