# spring boot + apache camel + mongodb integration issue

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am new to apache camel, just started. I have a spring boot (MVC) + mongodb project already running fine, when I am trying to integrate it with apache camel I am getting exception on console. As per my understanding on exception spring boot is trying to say that I cannot use default annotaion `@Component` on camel Route file when I am using `@ComponentScan(basePackages="packagePath")` anywhere else in the project, since it is a MVC architecture, I have Controller, Service & Repository which I cannot ignore, please help me solve this issue.

**Console Exception**

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2018-03-15 17:17:55.426
>   ERROR 744 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to process import candidates for configuration class
>   [com.era.conf.ApplicationConfiguration]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.health.HealthCheckRoutesAutoConfiguration
>   due to org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver not
>   found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class.
>   This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework
>   package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by
>   mistake)  at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:616)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:548)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   com.era.conf.ApplicationConfiguration.main(ApplicationConfiguration.java:12)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not
>   evaluate condition on
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.health.HealthCheckRoutesAutoConfiguration
>   due to org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver not
>   found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class.
>   This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework
>   package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by
>   mistake)  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:55)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:109)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:217)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:606)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     ... 15 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver     at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.isEnabled(HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.java:49)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.20.2.jar:2.20.2]    at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.evaluate(HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.java:42)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.20.2.jar:2.20.2]    at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.GroupCondition.getMatchOutcome(GroupCondition.java:40)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.20.2.jar:2.20.2]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]  ... 18
>   common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
>     ... 22 common frames omitted

**POM**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.2</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**ApplicationConfiguration**

```
package com.era.conf;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.era.controller")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfiguration.class, args);
    }

}
```

**EmailResponseController**

```
package com.era.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/emailResponse")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.era.service")
public class EmailResponseController {

    @Autowired private EmailResponseService serv;

    @RequestMapping("/read")
    public EmailResponseModel ExchangeServerEmailsReader() {
        return serv.ExchangeServerEmailsReader();
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
package com.era.service;

@Service
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.era.repository")
public class EmailResponseServiceImpl implements EmailResponseService {

    @Autowired private EmailResponseRepository repo;

    @Override
    public EmailResponseModel ExchangeServerEmailsReader() {
        final EmailResponseModel emailModel = new EmailResponseModel();
        emailModel.setEmail(readEmailsFromExchangeServer());

        return repo.save(emailModel);
    }
}
```

**CamelRouteClass**

```
package com.era.route;

@Component
public class CamelRouteClass extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:C://response?noop=true").to("file:C://response2");
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with camel. Why are you using `@ComponentScan` multiple times?

Comment: Can you suggest how should I use it otherwise ?

Comment: Edit the question and mention the packages of all the classes you mentioned above.

Comment: @pvpkiran Package added in classes

Comment: put your class `ApplicationConfiguration` under `com.era` and remove your `@ComponentScan` from everywhere and test

Comment: I removed `@ComponentScan` from everywhere and left only on ApplicationConfiguration everything worked fine. But when I added `@Component` on `CamelRouteClass` then again I an getting same exception which I was getting earlier.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that **RelaxedPropertyResolver** has been removed in the latest release of spring-boot (2.0.0.RELEASE). However, the latest camel-spring-boot-starter module (2.20.2 when writing this) still depends on the missing RelaxedPropertyResolver.

To solve the issue until there is a new version of Camel you need to downgrade spring-boot to 1.5.10.RELEASE.

Comment: Thanks @ShamimAhmad for figuring this out, I didn't feel like downgrading Spring Boot!

It seems the **RelaxedPropertyResolver** was introduced in Camel version 2.18.2.  
Camel 2.18.1 works for me in conjunction with Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE.

Comment: Starting from version 2.22.0, Camel supports Spring Boot 2. See release note http://camel.apache.org/camel-2220-release.html