# Is apache camel compatible with Springboot 2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

Which version of apache-camel is compatible with Springboot 2.0?

I keep getting this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.isEnabled (HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.java:49)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.evaluate (HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.GroupCondition.getMatchOutcome (GroupCondition.java:40)
```

Comment: I tweeted also about which Camel version that supports SB2. Its easy to remember as its Camel with all the number 2's, eg 2.22: https://twitter.com/davsclaus/status/972144268017061888

Comment: Its documented on top of the release notes which version of Spring Boot is supported, for example on Camel 2.21 you see: http://camel.apache.org/camel-2210-release.html

Answer (score 3):

It is not yet compatible as it is using Spring 1.15.x. support is planned for Camel 2.22.

[Migrated Spring boot 1.5 to 2.0, unable to start app getting: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282505/migrated-spring-boot-1-5-to-2-0-unable-to-start-app-getting-java-lang-classnot)